# mapnik generate_tiles.py returns memory error

Tags: python, openstreetmap, mapnik

I am trying to create tiles using [generate_tiles.py](http://svn.openstreetmap.org/applications/rendering/mapnik/generate_tiles.py) and every time I run the script, I get following error:

> Exception in thread Thread-2:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
>     File "render_tiles.py", line 114, in loop
>       self.render_tile(tile_uri, x, y, z)
>     File "render_tiles.py", line 96, in render_tile
>       mapnik.render(self.m, im)
>   MemoryError

Here is my script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from math import pi,cos,sin,log,exp,atan
from subprocess import call
import sys, os
from Queue import Queue
import mapnik
import threading
import random
import argparse

custom_fonts_dir = '/usr/share/fonts/'
mapnik.register_fonts(custom_fonts_dir)

DEG_TO_RAD = pi/180
RAD_TO_DEG = 180/pi

# Default number of rendering threads to spawn, should be roughly equal to number of CPU cores available
NUM_THREADS = 4

def minmax (a,b,c):
    a = max(a,b)
    a = min(a,c)
    return a

class GoogleProjection:
    def __init__(self,levels=18):
        self.Bc = []
        self.Cc = []
        self.zc = []
        self.Ac = []
        c = 256
        for d in range(0,levels):
            e = c/2;
            self.Bc.append(c/360.0)
            self.Cc.append(c/(2 * pi))
            self.zc.append((e,e))
            self.Ac.append(c)
            c *= 2

    def fromLLtoPixel(self,ll,zoom):
         d = self.zc[int(zoom)]
         e = round(d[0] + float(ll[0]) * self.Bc[zoom])
         f = minmax(sin(DEG_TO_RAD * float(ll[1])),-0.9999,0.9999)
         g = round(d[1] + 0.5*log((1+f)/(1-f))*-self.Cc[zoom])
         return (e,g)

    def fromPixelToLL(self,px,zoom):
         e = self.zc[zoom]
         f = (px[0] - e[0])/self.Bc[zoom]
         g = (px[1] - e[1])/-self.Cc[zoom]
         h = RAD_TO_DEG * ( 2 * atan(exp(g)) - 0.5 * pi)
         return (f,h)



class RenderThread:
    def __init__(self, tile_dir, mapfile, q, printLock, maxZoom):
        self.tile_dir = tile_dir
        self.q = q
        self.m = mapnik.Map(256, 256)
        self.printLock = printLock
        # Load style XML
        mapnik.load_map(self.m, mapfile)
        # Obtain  projection
        self.prj = mapnik.Projection(self.m.srs)
        # Projects between tile pixel co-ordinates and LatLong (EPSG:4326)
        self.tileproj = GoogleProjection(maxZoom+1)


    def render_tile(self, tile_uri, x, y, z):
        # Calculate pixel positions of bottom-left & top-right
        p0 = (x * 256, (y + 1) * 256)
        p1 = ((x + 1) * 256, y * 256)

        # Convert to LatLong (EPSG:4326)
        l0 = self.tileproj.fromPixelToLL(p0, z);
        l1 = self.tileproj.fromPixelToLL(p1, z);

        # Convert to map projection (e.g. mercator co-ords EPSG:900913)
        c0 = self.prj.forward(mapnik.Coord(l0[0],l0[1]))
        c1 = self.prj.forward(mapnik.Coord(l1[0],l1[1]))

        # Bounding box for the tile
        if hasattr(mapnik,'mapnik_version') and mapnik.mapnik_version() >= 800:
            bbox = mapnik.Box2d(c0.x,c0.y, c1.x,c1.y)
        else:
            bbox = mapnik.Envelope(c0.x,c0.y, c1.x,c1.y)
        render_size = 256
        self.m.resize(render_size, render_size)
        self.m.zoom_to_box(bbox)
        self.m.buffer_size = 128

        # Render image with default Agg renderer
        im = mapnik.Image(render_size, render_size)
        mapnik.render(self.m, im)
        im.save(tile_uri, 'png256')


    def loop(self):
        while True:
            #Fetch a tile from the queue and render it
            r = self.q.get()
            if (r == None):
                self.q.task_done()
                break
            else:
                (name, tile_uri, x, y, z) = r

            exists= ""
            if os.path.isfile(tile_uri):
                exists= "exists"
            else:
                self.render_tile(tile_uri, x, y, z)
            bytes=os.stat(tile_uri)[6]
            empty= ''
            if bytes == 103:
                empty = " Empty Tile "
            self.printLock.acquire()
            print name, ":", z, x, y, exists, empty
            self.printLock.release()
            self.q.task_done()



def render_tiles(bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, minZoom=1,maxZoom=18, name="unknown", num_threads=NUM_THREADS):
    print "render_tiles(",bbox, mapfile, tile_dir, minZoom, maxZoom, name,")"

    # Launch rendering threads
    queue = Queue(32)
    printLock = threading.Lock()
    renderers = {}
    for i in range(num_threads):
        renderer = RenderThread(tile_dir, mapfile, queue, printLock, maxZoom)
        render_thread = threading.Thread(target=renderer.loop)
        render_thread.start()
        #print "Started render thread %s" % render_thread.getName()
        renderers[i] = render_thread

    if not os.path.isdir(tile_dir):
         os.mkdir(tile_dir)

    gprj = GoogleProjection(maxZoom+1)

    ll0 = (bbox[0],bbox[3])
    ll1 = (bbox[2],bbox[1])

    for z in range(minZoom,maxZoom + 1):
        px0 = gprj.fromLLtoPixel(ll0,z)
        px1 = gprj.fromLLtoPixel(ll1,z)
        print "fromlattolon"

        # check if we have directories in place
        zoom = "%s" % z
        if not os.path.isdir(tile_dir + zoom):
            os.mkdir(tile_dir + zoom)
        for x in range(int(px0[0]/256.0),int(px1[0]/256.0)+1):
            # Validate x co-ordinate
            if (x = 2**z):
                continue
            # check if we have directories in place
            str_x = "%s" % x
            if not os.path.isdir(tile_dir + zoom + '/' + str_x):
                os.mkdir(tile_dir + zoom + '/' + str_x)
            for y in range(int(px0[1]/256.0),int(px1[1]/256.0)+1):
                # Validate x co-ordinate
                if (y = 2**z):
                    continue
                str_y = "%s" % y
                tile_uri = tile_dir + zoom + '/' + str_x + '/' + str_y + '.png'
                # Submit tile to be rendered into the queue
                t = (name, tile_uri, x, y, z)
                queue.put(t)

    # Signal render threads to exit by sending empty request to queue
    for i in range(num_threads):
        queue.put(None)
    # wait for pending rendering jobs to complete
    queue.join()
    for i in range(num_threads):
        renderers[i].join()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    MIN_LON = '29.5732';
    MAX_LON = '35.0360';
    MIN_LAT = '-1.4840';
    MAX_LAT = '4.2144';
    bbox = ( MIN_LON, MIN_LAT,MAX_LON, MAX_LAT)
    style_file="/home/mossplix/projects/Dev/mapit/map/static/tilemill/uganda_districts.xml"
    tile_dir="/home/mossplix/projects/UnicefDev/mapit/map/static/tiles/"
    min_zoom=7
    max_zoom=14
    render_tiles(bbox, style_file, tile_dir, min_zoom, max_zoom)
```

Here is the mapnik config file
  [mapnik config](http://pastebin.com/xkC8qS7e) 
and here is the  [shapefile](http://www.ugandaclusters.ug/dwnlds/0010IM/GEO-IM-WG/2011/2011_Shape_Files/Uganda_District2010.zip). I compiled mapnik from source , so it should be good. what could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can tell that is `generate_tiles.py` originally, modified slightly.

A MemoryError indicates that you either are requesting an abnormally large image to be rendered or you have found a Mapnik bug.

Since the former is more likely I figure that you have made a mistake during modification of `generate_tiles.py`. So I took your script, overwrote the latest version in svn and got out a diff of the differences: https://gist.github.com/1197587.

On line #106 and #115 you likely want to use `==` not `=` because otherwise you are making very large x and y values that are invalid and may be the cause of very large image requests (that are wrong for a given tile).

Comment: i think the line #106 and #115 were typos (the intepreter catches them actually) . the error is still  <pre>Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "render_tiles.py", line 114, in loop
    self.render_tile(tile_uri, x, y, z)
  File "render_tiles.py", line 96, in render_tile
    mapnik.render(self.m, im)
MemoryError</pre>

Answer (score 0):

**Default number of rendering threads to spawn, should be roughly equal to number of CPU cores available
NUM_THREADS = 4**

I had exactly the same error with NUM_THREADS=4.
Change the default value of NUM_THREADS to 1. I have an i5 (4 cores/1 thread per core) and NUM_THREADS=4 is very unstable. With NUM_THREADS=1 it works fine. If it works with NUM_THREADS=1 for you, try with NUM_THREADS=2 and NUM_THREADS=3 if nothing crashed.